# How do I have foreman reload node.js when a file is changed?

Tags: node.js, heroku, foreman

I currently use [supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) to run my node.js app when developing locally. This has been great, but I currently store all my [configs](http://www.12factor.net/config) in my `.bash_profile`, I want to move them to a `.env` file.

Is there a way to get the environment loading features of **foreman** with the file watching features of **supervisor**?

One option is to add it to my `Procfile` like this, but I suspect that will mess up Heroku.

```
`local: supervisor web.js`
```

Comment: i think [supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) reload your nodejs app when detect file changes... "It runs your program, and watches for code changes, so you can have hot-code reloading-ish behavior", other thing its when you push your code to heroku it reloads your server, so only for your localhost you need supervisor or when your script crash heroku dont run it again?

Comment: Just need it for local development so I don't have to manually `Ctl-C` the running node.js app.

Comment: maybe you can use supervisor without foreman (?)

Comment: That's what I currently do, but supervisor does not support loading environment vars from a file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the solution I put together and it works great.

### Install [Rerun](https://github.com/alexch/rerun) and [Rb-fsevent](https://github.com/thibaudgg/rb-fsevent).

```
sudo gem install rerun rb-fsevent
```

### Install Foreman if you have not already.

```
sudo gem install foreman
```

### Put your environment variables in `.env` in the root of your project.

**Don't forget to add `.env` to your `.gitignore`, [don't want that sensitive info in your code](http://www.12factor.net/config)**

```
echo '.env' >> .gitignore
```

### Here is what my `Procfile` looks like

```
web: node web.js
```

### Now just start like this

```
rerun foreman start web
```

### Extra Credit, create an alias

```
echo "alias rrun='rerun foreman start web'" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: hi. any idea why this doesn't work for me? after I change some file I get EADDRINUSE which means the process didn't actually stop and free the port to which it was listening

Comment: @Guard can you post some of your files in a gist so we can see what you're doing? I think by default `rerun` only watches for certain types of files.

Comment: I added proper masks and it restarts when I edit my coffee file. The problem is with EADDRINUSE which is thrown after the script *is* restarted

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to create another *Procfile* file for your development environment with your current configuration:

```
# Procfile.dev
web: supervisor app.js
```

And start `foreman` using that file

```
$ foreman start -f Procfile.dev
```

You can optionally exclude that file from your git repo

```
$ echo "Procfile.dev" >> .git/info/exclude
```

Comment: how can you get supervisor to run in debug mode with foreman.  it does not like the other process spawning.

Comment: For node-foreman users, change 2nd command to: `nf start -j Procfile.dev`